# I have an issue doing url rewriting in php in a subfolder because of my Wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I have a wordpress blog based in the root folder /. Besides that I have a sub domain in a subfolder. I want to do url rewriting in this subfolder (it's done in php with a 404 redirection rule in a .htaccess file). The redirection of the .htaccess is supposed to redirect to /subfolder/index.php .

My problem is that it doesn't work once it's uploaded on the server. The url http://mywebsite.com/subfolder/the-file-im-lookingfor.html keeps redirecting to the 404 error page of my wordpress blog.

I guess this is because of the url rewriting of Wordpress. Is there any way I can solve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you remove the `-f` and `-d` flags from your `.htaccess` code? because it was placed there for a reason.

Comment: What are the contents of the `.htaccess` file, and in which folder is it located? You might need to add a `RewriteBase` rule if it's in `/subfolder/`. Realize that the rules in `.htaccess` files are applied to all subfolders, and thus to `/subfolder/` folder as well if it's in `/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 404 redirection rule, i.e. a flag in your htaccess that looks like this:

```
[R=404]
```

Then you are sending the browser a 404 HTTP response, so it definitely will send the browser to your 404 page. You may have meant to send a 301 redirect.

The way I would handle a subdomain is to set up virtual hosts in your httpd.conf file and set the DocumentRoot to /subfolder for the subdomain. Then, you can handle their rewrite rules separately by putting separate htaccess files in each folder.